# Input Ouput dimensions python keras

Tags: machine-learning, python, keras, scikit-learn, pandas

CODE

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('D:\\test.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 0:2].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 2].values   
print (X)

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X_0 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 0] = labelencoder_X_0.fit_transform(X[:, 0])
labelencoder_X_1 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 1] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(X[:, 1])
print (X)
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0,1])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
X = X[:, 0:]
X = X[:, 1:]
print (X)

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2)
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)
print (X_test)

import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import keras.utils

classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 6, init = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 9))
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 6, init = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
# Adding the output layer
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 1, init = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 10, nb_epoch = 100)

_, accuracy = classifier.evaluate(X, y)
print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy*100))


#predictions
dataset = pd.read_csv('D:\\test1.csv')
a = dataset.iloc[:, 0:2].values
labelencoder_a_0 = LabelEncoder()
a[:, 0] = labelencoder_a_0.fit_transform(a[:, 0])
labelencoder_a_1 = LabelEncoder()
a[:, 1] = labelencoder_a_1.fit_transform(a[:, 1])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0,1])
a = onehotencoder.fit_transform(a).toarray()
a = a[:, 0:]
a = a[:, 1:]

predictions = classifier.predict_classes(a)
# summarize the first 2 cases
for i in range(2):
    print('%s => %d' % (a[i].tolist(), predictions[i]))
```

data after label encoders looks like

```
[[0 0]
 [0 1]
 [0 2]
 [0 3]
 [0 4]
 [0 5]
 [0 6]
 [0 7]
 [0 8]]
```

after one-hot looks like

```
[[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

after [X_test = sc.transform(X_test)] looks like

```
[[ 0.          1.         -0.40824829 -0.40824829 -0.40824829 -0.40824829
  -0.40824829 -0.40824829 -0.40824829]
 [ 1.          0.         -0.40824829 -0.40824829 -0.40824829 -0.40824829
  -0.40824829 -0.40824829 -0.40824829]]
```

and X_train looks like

```
[[-0.40824829 -0.40824829 -0.40824829 -0.40824829  0.          2.44948974
   0.         -0.40824829 -0.40824829]
 [-0.40824829 -0.40824829 -0.40824829 -0.40824829  0.         -0.40824829
   0.         -0.40824829  2.44948974]
 [-0.40824829 -0.40824829 -0.40824829 -0.40824829  0.         -0.40824829
   0.          2.44948974 -0.40824829]
 [ 2.44948974 -0.40824829 -0.40824829 -0.40824829  0.         -0.40824829
   0.         -0.40824829 -0.40824829]
 [-0.40824829  2.44948974 -0.40824829 -0.40824829  0.         -0.40824829
   0.         -0.40824829 -0.40824829]
 [-0.40824829 -0.40824829 -0.40824829  2.44948974  0.         -0.40824829
   0.         -0.40824829 -0.40824829]
 [-0.40824829 -0.40824829  2.44948974 -0.40824829  0.         -0.40824829
   0.         -0.40824829 -0.40824829]]
```

It is trained successfully. But when i run prediction code 
it gives error

```
Error when checking input: expected dense_205_input to have shape (9,) but got array with shape (6,)
```

variable (a) after one_hot looks like

```
[[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

I can't understand what is the problem with my prediction sample.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem originates in the fact that your testing set consists of examples of just 6 possible classes, while your model is trained with a training set of 9 different labels.

When converting the test set to one-hot-encoding, you need to add the number of possible labels as the 'n_values' parameter. Otherwise by default it relies on the number of classes in the test set (which is 6 in you case).

Comment: O yesss thanks a lot. The error is removed by using n_value parameter. but how ??? i mean what n_value do with my data set.

Comment: Only you know the answer to this question. How many different classes do you want your model to be able to recognize and classify?

Comment: only 2. i have set it with 0 and 1.